# I have XML file I want change its element value through python. change its value if "No" changed to "NA", and other than "Yes"

Tags: python-3.x, xml

**Data.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<inno:dom xmlns:inno="http://innodatalabs.com/innodom">
    <inno:meta>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-61">Yes</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-64">No</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-67">Personal Information</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-68">Non-Personal Information</inno:datapoint>
    </inno:meta>
</inno:dom>
```

**Output should like**
**Data.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<inno:dom xmlns:inno="http://innodatalabs.com/innodom">
    <inno:meta>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-61">Yes</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-64">NA</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-67">Yes</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-68">Yes</inno:datapoint>
    </inno:meta>
</inno:dom>
```

*if the value is "No" change to "NA" if the value is other than "Yes" or "No" change to "Yes" *

Answer (score -1):

You could use regex for quick results:

```py
import re

x = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<inno:dom xmlns:inno="http://innodatalabs.com/innodom">
    <inno:meta>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-61">Yes</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-64">No</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-67">Personal Information</inno:datapoint>
        <inno:datapoint idref="text-68">Non-Personal Information</inno:datapoint>
    </inno:meta>
</inno:dom>
"""
result = re.sub(r">([^<\n]+)<\/", lambda x: ">NA</" if x.group() == ">No</" else ">Yes</", x)
print(result)
```

But as @mzjn pointed out, in general it's not a great idea to change XML files using regex.

Please see [ElementTree and how to modify XML files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file).

Example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

if __name__ == "__main__":
    namespace_uri = "http://innodatalabs.com/innodom"
    ET.register_namespace('inno', namespace_uri)
    tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root.iter("{{{0}}}datapoint".format(namespace_uri)):
        text = child.text
        if text == "No":
            child.text = "NA"
        else:
            child.text = "Yes"
    tree.write("output.xml")
```

where `test.xml` is your example.

Comment: Using regular expressions to process XML is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @mzjn You are right. This is a quick solution. To create a true process I would use something like [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).